# Move an ADObject into a SubOU With Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add users to SubOU's via PowerShell.  The OU structure is as follows:

- capsuleco.com (domain)

  - CapsuleUsers (OU)

    - NMUsers (OU)

I have the following script for creating a new user in AD and adding them to the CapsuleUsers OU:

```
$name = Read-Host "User Name"
$email = Read-Host "Email"
$SAM = Read-Host "Sam Account Name"
$password = (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Account Password")

New-ADUser -Name $name -UserPrincipalName $name@capsuleco.com -DisplayName $name -SamAccountName $SAM -Email $email -Account Password $password

Get-ADUser $name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=CapsuleComputers, DC=capsuleco, DC=com"
```

This script works, it successfully adds a user to the CapsuleComputers OU. However, when I try add a user to a SubOU, such as the "NMUsers" OU, which resides within the CapsuleComputers OU via this method:

```
Get-ADUser $name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=CapsuleComputers, OU=NMUsers, DC=capsuleco, DC=com"
```

I get this error message:

*"The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted"*

What is the easiest way to move an ADObject into a subOU?

Comment: You have additional double quotes in your `-TargetPath` value!  ;-)  ... if that's not a typo here in SO.

Comment: That is a typo.  I will fix that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It would be "OU=NMUsers, OU=CapsuleComputers, DC=capsuleco, DC=com"

Comment: I set it to your recommendation and still get the same error "object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted."

Comment: You're inserting space characters in at places they don't belong, like here `- Account Password` an also in the path for the OU..

Comment: [1] it **really** is a bad idea to use `Read-Host` to enter user data and next blindly create a new user out of that input without **checking** anything.. [2] Open ADUC, right-click the OU you want as targetpath, select Properties and copy what is in the `distinguishedName` of that OU. Use that unaltered as TargetPath. [3] Check the parameters of [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser) and write these with their proper names. You'll notice it has a `Path` parameter, so you don't need to move the new user at all.